# Modal Dialog with click-through grey-out background

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog

Is it possible to create a modal dialog in JavaScript with a greyed-out background where everything in the background still registers click events?

(And is this good/bad practice?)

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: the good practice is to let people know where to click, what they click and why they should. click or trick ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course it is.

```
.your-backdrop-selector {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

This is web. It's virtual space. Virtually anything is possible. If it's not, you're **doing it wrong**. :)

Can I use: [pointer-events](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events)

Answer (score 2):

You don't even need javascript.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.box {
  height: 100vh;
  transition: background .25s ease;
}
.box:hover {
  background: #f00;
}
.modal {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border: 1px solid grey;
  background: plum;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 9999px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>

<div class="modal">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa explicabo enim fuga, eaque necessitatibus nostrum officiis commodi atque aut, voluptatum in soluta a, molestiae deleniti!</p>
</div>
```